# libGDX - Button is set to down even if outside of bounds

Tags: java, libgdx, clicklistener

I'm am trying to properly setup button clicks for my UI. I want my buttons to respond right after clicking them instead of releasing by using ClickListeners touchDown method.

I've created a class which creates and displays a table with text input:

```
public class InputBox {

    public static float OFFSET = 20;

    private Table table;

    private TextField inputField;

    private TextButton okButton;
    private TextButton closeButton;

    private String saveText;

    private TextButtonStyle style;

    private Skin skin;

    public InputBox(Skin skin, float x, float y, float width, float height, boolean visible) {

        this.skin = skin;

        table = new Table();

        // Creating a new style as suggested.
        style = new TextButtonStyle();
        style.up = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_up");
        style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_down");
        style.font = skin.getFont("default");

        inputField = new TextField("", skin);

        okButton = new TextButton("Ok", style);     
        okButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                if (button != Buttons.LEFT) {

                    return false;
                }
                Game.resources.getSound("click_2").play();
                table.setVisible(false);

                if (inputField.getText().equals("")) {

                    saveText = null;
                    return false;
                }

                saveText = inputField.getText();                                
                return true;
            }

        });

        closeButton = new TextButton("Close", style);
        closeButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {           

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                if (button != Buttons.LEFT) {

                    return false;
                }
                Game.resources.getSound("click_2").play();

                saveText = null;                

                table.setVisible(false);                

                return true;
            }       
        });

        table.setVisible(visible);

        table.setX(x);
        table.setY(y);

        table.setWidth(width);
        table.setHeight(height);

        table.add(inputField).colspan(2).center().width(width - OFFSET).expand().padRight(2);
        table.row();
        table.add(okButton).width(width / 2 - OFFSET / 2).right();
        table.add(closeButton).width(width / 2 - OFFSET / 2).left();
        table.pad(5);
    }

    public void setUnclicked() {


        style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_up"); 

        // I think these two lines ar uneeded.
        okButton.setStyle(style);
        closeButton.setStyle(style);
    }

    public void setClicked() {

        style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_down");

        // Same here.
        okButton.setStyle(style);
        closeButton.setStyle(style);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {

        inputField.setText(text);
    }

    public String getSaveTextOnce() {

        String temp = saveText;

        saveText = null;

        return temp;
    }

    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {

        table.setBackground(background);
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {

        return table.isVisible();
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {

        table.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public Table getTable() { 

        return table;
    }
}
```

The table is being set to visible after clicking a different button:

```
// Save map button.
saveMap = new ImageButton(new ImageButtonStyle());
saveMap.getStyle().imageUp = uiSkin.getDrawable("save");
saveMap.getStyle().up = uiSkin.getDrawable("button_flat_up");
saveMap.getStyle().down = uiSkin.getDrawable("button_flat_down");

saveMap.addListener(new ClickListener() {

    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        if (button != Buttons.LEFT) {

            return false;
        }

        Game.resources.getSound("click_2").play();

        if (saveBox.isVisible()) {

            saveBox.setVisible(false);  
            saveBox.setUnclicked();
            return false;
        }
        saveBox.setVisible(true);
        saveBox.setClicked();

        return true;
    }       
});
```

The entire class for the saveMap button: http://pastebin.com/62ZGfcch

However, if I close the table by clicking the "ok" or "close" button and click and hold the mouse over the show table button, the table reappears with last clicked button being held down.

This video illustrates whats happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf3WzU8G4dE&feature=youtu.be

If I move the mouse while holding it down, the last clicked button on the table resets to its normal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would recommend you to rather use a TextButtonStyle instance for setting the style of the buttons rather than a Skin instance.

You could somehow get the TextButton's references to the *saveMap.addListener* anonymous inner class. Then you could manualy set the style of the Ok and Cancel TextButton's, something like this:

```
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

    Game.resources.getSound("click_2").play();

    if (saveBox.isVisible()) {

        saveBox.setVisible(false); 
        okButtonReference.setStyle(unclickedTextButtonStyle) // Not-clicked TextButtonStyle as parameter

        cancelButtonReference.setStyle(unclickedTextButtonStyle) // Not clicked TextButtonStyle as parameter.
        return false;
    }
    saveBox.setVisible(true);

    return true;
}
```

By forcing the TextButton to change it's TextButtonStyle by calling setStyle() you can be confident that the button will change.

Also i noticed that you are not calling the debug() method on the Table object. This is not necessary but it is advisable:

```
    table.add(inputField).colspan(2).center().width(width - OFFSET).expand().padRight(2);
    table.row();
    table.add(okButton).width(width / 2 - OFFSET / 2).right();
    table.add(closeButton).width(width / 2 - OFFSET / 2).left();
    table.pad(5);
    table.debug();
```

Comment: Created these methods and used them how you suggested using TextButtonStyles:

 public void setUnclicked() 
 public void setClicked() 

However the issue persists. I'm calling the setClicked method right after calling the setVisible method.

Comment: @Edd Did you set the Style using someTextButton.setStyle(textButtonStyleInstance); ?? Because from the code that you just provided i can't see that you are calling this method.

Comment: I modify the current style instead of using a new one:
        public void setUnclicked() {  
  style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_up");
 }
 public void setClicked() {  
  style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_down");
 }

I call setUnclicked() after I hide the table and setClicked() after I set the table to visible (code doesn't fit inside the comment).

Comment: Yes i understand that, but you also have to call setStyle(); on the TextButton instance. @Edd

Comment: Added setStyle() but it had the same effect:
style.down = skin.getDrawable("button_normal_up");
closeButton.setStyle(style);

Perhaps there is some issue with how libGDX handles the touchDown event? I've recorded a video showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf3WzU8G4dE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Update your code as it is now and add all the classes that have anything to do with this code so that i can see what the code looks like now... and we'll figure this out.. @Edd

Comment: @Edd - Try setting style.up instead of style.down in your setUnclicked() method.

Comment: Yes, the setUnclicked() and setClicked() methods are indeed not needed as you are setting the style.down and style.up as you are constructing the TextButtonStyle object. What i would suggest is that you create 2 seperate TextButtonStyle's one for button_normal_up and one for button_normal_down. In your case the setStyle() method is not actually doing anything since you have one instance of the TextButtonStyle object. So make 2 seperate objects and setStyle(someTextButton) on the previous button. Although style.down and style.up should work, but sometimes they seem to cause trouble.

Comment: The issue is still occurring, current code: http://pastebin.com/g4037mHL

Looking at Actor javadocs, at the setVisible method it says:
"If false, the actor will not be drawn and will not receive touch events."
Maybe the case is that the events are not handled properly after I set the table to visible again?

Comment: It might be. I'm more and more starting to think that it's a bug so i'm going to suggest something that at first glance might seem controversial. I suggest that you create a method createBox() or something that will reinitialize the whole thing again and again, by that i mean the TextButton instances and everything that has something to do with this. This might seem as a bad idea but if you think about it you are only creating a few objects so memory is not a problem at all. But as you re-create all those objects make sure to set the previous ones to NULL so they are ready for the GC.

Comment: If you reinitialize the whole thing there should not be a problem, because all of the boxes components will be recreated, but again... make sure to clean everything that has to do with those objects. You might wan't to call System.gc() but as you probably know the Garbage Collector is a bit stubborn and only arrives when the memory is low.

Comment: That does seem like a temporary solution, I'll see what libGDX forums have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

After more fiddling I found out that the way I setup my games InputProcessor was causing this issue. I did not handle the touchUp event properly.

```
Game.inputs.addProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        releasedButton = -1;

        if (UI.isOver()) {

            return false;
        }
        if (button == Buttons.LEFT) {

            releasedButton = Buttons.LEFT;
        }
        if (button == Buttons.RIGHT) {

            releasedButton = Buttons.RIGHT;
        }       
        return true; // <--- setting this to false fixes the issue
    }           
});
```